# How is such IndexOutOfRangeException possible when debugger shows the index is not out of range?

Tags: c#

This is the weirdest runtime error I ever got in C#:

a)
[image]
b)
[image]

This is ONE BREAKPOINT.
You can see the `Messages` array has the length of 128.
You can see AT THE SAME TIME the requested array index is 3 (or 2, I'm not sure if the index was incremented or not, but it should not matter here, index 3, length 128, so 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 127 should all be valid indices).

How is the method called? A WebSocket client listens to messages. The messages are written to a circular buffer. The buffer is constant. Preallocated at the session start. So after offset 127 there is offset 0 and so on. It is important that the application should see the latest 127 messages so it can search for interesting stuff. This is a workaround for malformed content sent by the server. The server sends the message in wrong order. Let's say it sends state and updates. But in reverse order. First I get updates, then the state to which the updates are for. With that little trick it works. For hours and hours. And once upon a time my app dies. Being patient and leaving the app for a few hours under VS debugger I got this error. W T F ? !

BTW, there is no concurrency here. There is only ONE session running in the process. The function as you can see is synchronous. There is one thread that reads the messages from the WS server.

There are other threads that communicate to the clients what happens on the remote server, but it seems like the remote server reader have crashed. But what did just happen? The array is 128 items long. All the time. Created over an hour before the crash. The index is 2 or 3 - so within the valid range.

The only explanation I can think of the VS debugger lies to me. Something else have crashed and the debugger shows me wrong part of the code. What now? How would you proceed to debug that stuff furtner?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Woof.Crypto {

    class MessageBuffer {

        public int Capacity { get; }

        public long CurrentId { get; private set; }


        public MessageBuffer(int capacity = 128) {
            Messages = new (long, object)[Capacity = capacity];
        }

        public void Write(object message) {
            Messages[CurrentOffset++] = (CurrentId++, message);
            if (CurrentOffset >= Capacity) CurrentOffset = 0;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetFromId(long id) => Messages.Where(i => i.Item1 > id).OrderBy(i => i.Item1).Select(i => i.Item2);

        readonly (long, object)[] Messages;
        int CurrentOffset;

    }

}
```

Comment: How the Messages array is initialized? Did you check what's the value of Length property of array when the exception occurs?

Comment: Can you please post the code also?

Comment: Here's the code, the array length is shown on picture `a`. It's 128, set in the constructor.

Comment: Are you debugging Release code, or Debug code?

Comment: When you click "View Details" you should at least be able to verify on which thread this happens. I would pick GetFromId() for this error.

Comment: Does the crash *always* happen when `CurrentOffset` is 2 or 3?

Comment: could you also post the calling site of the write method?

Comment: I find it's a good idea to pay attention to Sherlock Holmes: "*when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth*". This looks and smells and feels like a multithreaded race, and there's a plausible way a race could cause that exception there (if we let the debugger show you a slightly out of date value for `CurrentOffset`). I know you've said there isn't a race, but I'd really question that: add a lock, does it go away? Add locking which throws if the lock isn't immediately available: does that ever throw?

Comment: Debug, IDK if always. It takes a long time for it to crash. I get the messages from the server all the time. So the code is executed every couple of seconds. It must roll the index many times before it crashes.

Comment: I added the lock, let's wait and see. Why should it be a race condition? The code is called from the `MessageReceived` method, that internally is called by `HttpListener` instance. In a loop. One thread. From one and only connection to the server.

Comment: @Harry I've added an answer with a suggestion for how to test the locking: it should be a quicker test, as a positive result is a (different) exception, rather than the lack of an exception, so you just run it until it fails one way or the other

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say why you might be seeing multithreaded access without seeing your whole code which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Harry Also, stick a `Thread.Sleep` inside `Write`, see if that triggers the issue sooner. Also decrease the size of `Messages` to 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

I know you said this isn't multithreaded, but it has "race" written all over it. If you do have multithreaded access:

1. It's expected that you'd only get an error randomly, after a long period.
2. You can get the crash you're seeing, as two threads run `Messages[CurrentOffset++]` before one of them has a chance to run `if (CurrentOffset >= Capacity) CurrentOffset = 0;`
3. The debugger would probably show that `CurrentOffset` has a small value, as it takes the debugger a little while to break, in which time another thread did manage to reset `CurrentOffset` to 0, and then increment it.

I recommend doing something like this:

```
private readonly object lockObject = new object();
public void Write(object message) {
    if (!Montor.TryEnter(lockObject))
        throw new Exception("We have a race!");

    Messages[CurrentOffset++] = (CurrentId++, message);
    if (CurrentOffset >= Capacity) CurrentOffset = 0;

    Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
}
```

My money's on that throwing the exception soonish, and you won't see your original crash.

(Note that I haven't followed best practice here: I'm not using `TryEnter(object, ref bool)` and I'm not using a `try/finally`. They don't matter for this particular little bit of debugging.)

You can also stick a `Thread.Sleep` in there if you want to try and trigger the race sooner. You can also try decreasing the size of `Messages` to a small value, such as 1 or 2, to try and trigger your original exception sooner.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to walk my dog, the code with lock is running now, if it won't crash after an hour or 2, I'll add the check as in your example to see if it's the case. Then probably a couple of hours of testing to trigger the error. Well - maybe the `HttpListener` plays some tricks that a little lock can tame? We'll see. So... The index is 127, valid, then another thread enters before the index is reset in the next line to zero. Maybe.

Comment: I'd put money on that, but I am guessing. Without seeing your `HttpListener` code I can't comment on that I'm afraid

Comment: @Harry Another thing to test is just putting a breakpoint in `Write`, letting it break a few times while keeping an eye on `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` in a watch window (or check the current thread in the Threads window), and just see whether that's changing... That tells you whether your `HttpListener` is unexpectedly multi-threaded (but not whether those two threads are accessing `Write` at the same time)

Comment: The listener code is pretty standard. Default System `HttpListener` implementation. A long running task is started, in the loop there is an infinite waiting for a message, then the message is written into the buffer. The code is however very modular, so interfaces, classes deriving from classes based on other classes. Not a spaghetti, but a little too large to paste here.

Comment: Hence the need for a [mcve]. Is a `MessageBuffer` shared across different long-running tasks? Do you have any async which isn't awaited? Etc, there are many things which could be hiding in there.

Comment: @Harry Any progess? I'm curious!

Comment: I left the lock on the block with buffer write and it helped. The app works like 3 days in a row, didn't crash once. It was it - I guess the data receive events may somehow come concurrently, I didn't expect that but apparently that was it. Thanks again, it's something about ducks here, when it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck then it's a duck. I mean - race condition ;)

Comment: Good to hear, thanks! It would be worth understanding what your concurrency model is I think -- this probably isn't the only bit of thread-unsafe code around!

Comment: It was surely a point where I expected a single thread (I was wrong). The other end of the app is a server for multiple client connections - so it's expected to be concurrent. I also tested that with a bot "DOS-ing" the server with connections and misbehavior (dropping connections without close handshake). Passes. I wouldn't risk to launch such test to the remote server - I would get my IP banned ;)